# How to select/delete/yank the contents of only the current fold?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions, folding, object-motions, custom-text-object

When using `foldmethod=marker`, how do you select or reference exactly the contents of the current fold?  I want to swap the order of two folds.  If they were paragraphs, I would do `dap` `{` `p`.  However, I can't find a corresponding `daz`.  I think the answer is obvious, but I sure can't find it here or on Google.  Possibly related to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12717/1430).

MCVE:

```
Fold 1 {{{

}}}
Fold 2 {{{

}}}
Fold 3 {{{
}}}

- vi: set foldmethod=marker: -
```

Put the cursor on `Fold 2`.  Then `dzj` removes the contents of `Fold 2`, and also the `Fold 3` line.  Or, put the cursor on the `}}}` of `Fold 2`, and `dzk` kills the end of `Fold 1` as well.  Similar results from `d[z` and `d]z`.

`zd` removes the fold markers, but I want to actually grab the contents of the fold.

If I could do something like `viz` `d`, that would work great — but searches for "visual" and "folding" are giving me lots of hits about `v<motion>zf`, which is not what I want.

So far, the only options I have found are:

- to delete, `zc` `dd` (close the fold, then delete the resulting single line).
- to select in visual mode, `zc` `V`

Are those indeed the Right Things to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no text object for folds in vim, but there is a plugin which provides them, `az`/`iz`: https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-fold

Here are vanilla alternatives:

- `vi{`/`va{`.  This may or may not select what you want, depending on whether your markers are in comments or not.
- `[zV]z`.  Alternatively you can replace `V` with any operator.
- make your own: `xnoremap az [zo]z`, `xnoremap iz [zjo]zk`

Comment: I wound up using [somini's fork of vim-textobj-fold](https://github.com/somini/vim-textobj-fold), which has some updates that haven't made it upstream yet.  Thanks!

Comment: That plugin (or the forked one suggested by @cxw) does not work for me. I get an error message on the loading of the plugin.

Answer (score 6):

To delete the current fold, you simply have `zd` for instance

Otherwise, you could also define an operator-pending mode mapping with for instance:

```
:onoremap iz :<c-u>normal! [zV]z<cr>
```

Which will permit stuff like `diz`, `ciz`, `yiz`, `=iz` and so on.

BTW, the related visual mode mapping would be:

```
:xnoremap iz [zo]z
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a closed fold, any regular action will apply to the whole fold.

To delete closed fold under cursor then, you need only type `D` or `d$`. To yank it to the clipboard, `Y` or `y$`.

You can similarly, for example, delete three folds from the current fold, inclusive, and place them in the system clipboard, by typing `"+d3j`.

Answer (score 0):

I have defined a simple macro. Anywhere in a fold, delete the fold content:

```
map dz ?{{{<CR>:.+1,/}}}/-1d<CR>
```

Comment: Note that this relies on `foldmethod=marker foldmarker={{{,}}}`